# Jupyter Notebook to_csv files are downloaded as excel workbook

Tags: python, download, jupyter

I have a new laptop that I am running Jupyter Notebook. I have used Jupyter Notebook on a previous laptop and didn't run into this issue. When I try to export a dataframe using to_csv, the file shows up in the directory as csv. When I try to download it, it downloads the file as Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet.When I try to open the downloaded files in this format, excel gives me a warning saying file format and extension don't match. I can still open the file, but then I have to delimit it with a file. Where can I change that I want to download the file as csv and not this 97-2003 worksheet file. If it helps, I am using google chrome.

Here is what I am using codewise:

dftest.to_csv('q1data.csv')

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Just added it to original post.

Comment: "When I try to download it, it downloads the file as Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet." How exactly are you downloading it? Clicking on it in the file navigator and then choosing the right form in a dialog box that comes up? Often your local system will default to trying to link certain file types to specific programs, yet usually you can override that if you take the time and opt for your selection. Or are you in a Microsoft specific product or environment when you try to download and it is Microsoft favoring you use their products. Your post lacks some of the details to discern this.

Comment: I am downloading these files through the jupyter directory by clicking the box next to the name of the file and clicking download at the top of the directory. Other options besides download are open, rename, duplicate and delete.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, maybe you can try the following:

1. Try to manually change the downloaded file from .xls to .csv
2. Check maybe there is a setting in chrome that keeps converting the files to xls.